# Dota 2 Hotkey problem

Tags: dota-2

I am using legacy keys. I have set my item key bindings to legacy (numpad keys) + quickcasts are set as presented above.

Yet I still have ZXCVVBN keys bound as item keys, the chat wheel resets to Y key, which makes a lot problems especially when playing invoker which in legacy mode uses V for ghost walk, B for deafening blast and Y for cold snap.

The problem occured after new layout had been introduced, disappeared for a while and now returned to it's broken state.

I usually deal with it by setting the 'Y' key or w/e to something and then reset it to none, the problem disappears until dota is restarted.

How can I make those changes permament?
[image: my binds]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was enabling the console and unbinding the keys through *unbind* command (f.e unbind z)
If toggling the console in the options in dota doesn't work rightclick on dota in steam library -> properties -> set launch options -> add -console